# Add extra line before declaring first field property in class

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, prettier

I just installed prettier on my vscode and I found out prettier is removing a line before first property in a class in TypeScript.

This is before save

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
                                                  <- this line gets removed
  user$: Observable<User> = this.auth.user$.pipe(
    tap((user) => (!user ? this.toLogin() : user))
  );

  constructor(
    private auth: AuthService,
    private router: Router,
    private sidebar: SidebarService
  ) {}
}
```

This is after save

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  user$: Observable<User> = this.auth.user$.pipe(
    tap((user) => (!user ? this.toLogin() : user))
  );

  constructor(
    private auth: AuthService,
    private router: Router,
    private sidebar: SidebarService
  ) {}
}
```

Is there any way I could configure this?

Answer (score 1):

> Prettier is not a kitchen-sink code formatter that attempts to print your code in any way you wish. It is opinionated.

This quote taken from Prettier's page on options. https://prettier.io/docs/en/option-philosophy.html

Personally, I love Prettier and would advise you to roll with it